# How to translate "get element by id" into typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html5-audio

My Project runs on Angular 8 with typescript.

Im trying to get an html audio element by id and store it in a variable.
Then i want to get the duration out of the Element and store it in another variable.

As seen in a working example, in Javascript, this would go as:

**HTML**

```
<audio id="music" preload="true">
  <source src="./assets/img/hollywood.mp3">
```

**JS**

```
var music = document.getElementById('music'); 
var duration = music.duration;
```

now my translation to typescript is this:

**TS**

```
public music = <HTMLAudioElement>document.getElementById("music");
public duration = this.music.duration;
```

But when i load the page, i get the error "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.music is null"
and i dont get why.

Comment: And if you remove `this` from `this.music.duration` ? I am not familiar with TS.

Comment: It's not a typescript error. `preload=true` tells the browser to fetch the audio first. But it's not done loading by the time you execute the script

Comment: @Fasani, if i remove this, the variable music is not recognized

Comment: @MonteCristo if i remove that, the same error is printed

Comment: Access DOM-elements in `ngAfterViewInit()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) and [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) using a template reference variable to keep things the Angular way. Try the following

Template

```html
<audio #stream autoplay (play)="onPlay()">
  <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Example.ogg">
</audio>
```

Controller

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
export class AppComponent {

  audioPlayer: HTMLAudioElement;

  @ViewChild('stream') set playerRef(ref: ElementRef<HTMLAudioElement>) {
    this.audioPlayer = ref.nativeElement;
  }

  onPlay() {
    console.log(this.audioPlayer.duration);
  }
}
```

It binds the `nativeElement` of the element reference to the `audioPlayer` variable using `set`.

`ngAfterViewInit()` cannot guarantee accessing the `duration` would return the correct value since the audio may not have started playing. In that case, it would return `null`. So I bound it to the `play` event to get the duration.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nq785o)

Comment: small addition: when adding preload true, the duration can be accessed from ngafterviewinit with this.duration = this.audioplayer.duration . Just in case someone wonders how this did work.

Answer (score 0):

Add #nameForYourRef

```
<audio #myAudio preload="true">
  <source src="./assets/img/hollywood.mp3">
</audio>
```

Then access your element on viewInit

```
@ViewChild('myAudio') myAudioRef: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Console log some methods to see that it is working
    console.log(
      this.myAudioRef.nativeElement.play,
      this.myAudioRef.nativeElement.pause,
    )
  }
```

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a8jahz